# Is there a date/time format that does not have spaces?

Tags: linux, date

I have a CGI script that will convert a given string to a date/time using the unix `date` command.  I'm looking for a format that can easily be embedded to a URL without the need for escaping with a `%20`.  The client that is building the date/time into the URL does not have a conversion to unix time (seconds since epoch) and does not have a way to convert to the offset from zulu (ISO8601 will not work).  However, it is possible to reformat the date/time used to build the URL in many other ways.

Are there any other options to build a datetime in a non-spaced format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a simple work around.  Simply use underscores for spaces and do a `tr` in the CGI script before converting to a date.  It looks something like this:

`stamp="$(echo $stamp|tr _ ' '|xargs -0 date -d)"`

Then use a date that looks something like this:

`26_Oct_2010_11:57:56_CDT`

which converts to:

`date -d "26 Oct 2010 11:57:56 CDT"`

Answer (score 46):

```
$ date "+%F-%T"
2010-10-25-16:23:14
```

Comment: Thank you for response but I still need a timezone.  Also, `date -d "2010-10-25-16:23:14"` didn't work.

Comment: `date "+%F-%T-%Z"` gives the timezone too.

Answer (score 10):

The ISO 8601 format is perfect for this and is built-in to `date`.

Here are some examples at the various levels of supported precision:

```
$ date --iso-8601
2021-06-26
```

```
$ date --iso-8601=minutes
2021-06-26T16:01-0600
```

```
$ date --iso-8601=seconds
2021-06-26T16:01:23-0600
```

```
$ date --iso-8601=ns
2021-06-26T16:03:19,903115256-0600
```

See `man date` for more options.

Comment: Standard + no spaces + readable. This is the correct answer guys.